# gson from json was error expected in kotlin why?

Tags: kotlin

employee = Gson().fromJson(arguments?.getString("employee").orEmpty(), ProfileResponse.Employee::class.java)
arguments?.remove("employee")

Comment: fyi in my firebase employee show data must not be null, need help sir thank you

Comment: It's not clear what your question is exactly. Could you provide more code and show the exact error message?
Like this it's really hard to help you...

Comment: override fun setupData() {
  //employee = Gson().fromJson(arguments?.getString("employee"), ProfileResponse.Employee::class.java)


  //employee = Gson().fromJson(
  // arguments?.getString("employee").orEmpty(),
  // ProfileResponse.Employee::class.java
 // )
  //val newJson = Gson().toJson(json)

  val gson = Gson()
  employee = Gson().fromJson(
   arguments?.getString("employee"),
   ProfileResponse.Employee::class.java
  )
  val json = gson.toJson(employee)

  println(json)

  arguments?.remove("employee")
 }

Comment: this is my error sir

Comment: Yes but can you show the error message, not the code.
Can you also edit in the question and post it as actual code? It's really hard to read as plain text...